# How do i download google browser installation without a browser using windows command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, browser, download

I need to download and install Google Web browser without using a browser. My only option is windows command line. What are the commands I need to input to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't downloading the installer from another PC be much easier?

Comment: Why do you need to do it without a browser?

Answer (score -1):

You can use PowerShell. Anything like [this](https://gist.github.com/kurokikaze/350fe1713591641b3b42).

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Here we use links only as reference, but the answer should always contain the solution.